# Significant bundle size increase after upgrading from Angular 15 to 17

Tags: angular

After upgrading from Angular 15 to 17, my bundle increased in size by 141 KB. I'm not sure what to make of it. Did I do something wrong? Or is this to be expected?

Comment: Where exactly did you get this number? I've built an empty project, it shows the raw size 216 kB (183 for the main chunk and 33 for polyfills), I guess your project is not empty, so could you share some details? Have you updated some dependencies? A screenshot of bundle analytics with source-map-explorer would also help answer your question.

Comment: The application is much more than an empty, OOTB project. You can easily measure the increase using the budget in angular.json